# How to check for repeated elements from list and stop the while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

How do I stop the while loop only when each group has 3 members? (max. number for each group is 3)

When everyone is assigned to a group the loop must stop and say "Finish".

```
def get_group():
    group_1 = []
    group_2 = []
    while len(group_1) <= 3 and len(group_2) <= 3:
        name = input("Tell me your name: ")
        available_names = ["Tomás", "Fábio", "Rita", "Dany", "Inês", "Ana"]
        if name in available_names:
            given_group = random.randint(1, 2)
            if given_group == 1:
                group_1.append(given_group)
            else:
                group_2.append(given_group)
            print("You are in group " + str(given_group))
        else:
            print("Name not available")
    else:
        print("Finish")


get_group()
```

Comment: You mean you want to keep the loop running as long as the first group has less than 3 members or the second group has less than 3 members?

Comment: You should probably remove names from `available_names` as you group them.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I want to end the loop when both group 1 and group 2 have 3 members.

Comment: You are right! I'll do that!

Comment: You'll also need to ensure that you don't overpopulate one group.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the conditional with the while loop is a partial solution but doesn't solve the case of hitting say group 2 4 times in a row.

Code below does the following:

- Gets name
- Generates random group
- Checks if the target group is already full

  - If it is then add to other group
- Removes the name from the available names

```
def get_group():
    group_1 = []
    group_2 = []
    available_names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
    while True:
        name = input("Tell me your name: ")
        if name in available_names:
            r = random.randint(1, 2)
            if r == 1:
                if len(group_1) < 3:
                    group_1.append(name)
                    given_group = 1
                else:
                    group_2.append(name)
                    given_group = 2
            else:
                if len(group_2) < 3:
                    group_2.append(name)
                    given_group = 2
                else:
                    group_1.append(name)
                    given_group = 1
            print("You are in group " + str(given_group))
            available_names.pop(available_names.index(name))
        else:
            print("Name not available")
        if len(group_1) == 3 and len(group_2) == 3:
            break

    print(group_1)
    print(group_2)
    print("Finish")
```

It's not very elegant code, but I'll just use the excuse that it's to clearly show the process :p

Comment: That answered exactly my question, thank you very much! I didn't realize the logic behind the "while true" in this case but I think I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill both groups equally, you need to loop until you've allocated all the names, *and* you need to check for when one group is "full" so you can switch to the other one.

Since you want to assign all the names, it's simpler to remove the names from the set of available names as you assign them, and use that as the condition for the loop.  You can also simplify the process of picking a group by putting them into a dictionary rather than having two named variables (which requires a lot of copy+pasted code to keep straight).

```
import random


def get_group():
    available_names = {"Tomás", "Fábio", "Rita", "Dany", "Inês", "Ana"}
    groups = {1: [], 2: []}

    while available_names:
        # Pick a name, requiring it to be one of the available names.
        name = input("Tell me your name: ")
        if name not in available_names:
            print("Name not available")
            print(f"Available names: {', '.join(available_names)}")
            continue

        # Randomly pick a group.
        # If it's already full (3 names), default to the other group.
        given_group = random.randint(1, 2)
        if len(groups[given_group]) >= 3:
            given_group = 3 - given_group

        # Assign to the given group, and make the name unavailable.
        groups[given_group].append(name)
        available_names.remove(name)
        print(f"You are in group {given_group}")

    print("Finish")


get_group()
```

Comment: Wow! That's such a smart and short way to do it. I would have never thought of doing it like this. This really shows me how important it is to be concise.

Answer (score -1):

replace `<=` with `<` and replace `and` with `or` to check if either group still have less than 3 elements. once both have 3 elements `loop` will exit.

```
while len(group_1) < 3 or len(group_2) < 3:
```